# Virtual hosts on OpenLiteSpeed won't acknlowdge domain name

Tags: virtual, hosts, litespeed

I'm trying to set up a virtual host on OpenLiteSpeed 1.4.39. I've followed [the official guide](https://openlitespeed.org/mediawiki/index.php/Help:Name-Based_Virtual_Hosting), but OpenLiteSpeed just won't acknowledge my domain name, hence my virtual host won't start.

[image: Virtual host will not start and no domain defined]

I have however defined the desired domain name under **Virtual Host >  General > Domain Name**

[image: I've set the domain name to my desired domain]

Under listeners and Virtual Host Mappings, I've connected my virtual host, listener and domain name.

[image: Screenshot of settings]

But the virtual host will not start?
Does anyone have any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to "Dashboard" , the "Server Error Log" section , do you see any related info there?   it should state what's going on or why it fails.

Comment: Oh god, yes. It said *[ADMIN] authentication failed!*. Strange, because I've been able to see the interface, however running /usr/local/lsws/admin/misc/admpass.sh with my existing credentials resolved the issue.

Comment: bit of weird , yes , I only encountered such situation once as I login first and then I run admpass.sh changed my login info without log out and log in again.